# Differentiating under the integral sign. A step of the proof from Zorich's book

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $ f(x,t) $ be a real valued function defined on the product $ K\times \left[0,1\right] $, where $ K $ is a compact subset of $ \mathbb R $. Suppose $ f $ is continuous and continuously differentiable in $ x $.

I’m trying to show that the function
$$
g(x) = \int_0^1 f(x,t)\, \mathrm dt
$$
is continuously differentiable, and
$$
g^\prime(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)\, \mathrm dt\text{.}
$$

I’m reading the proof from Zorich’s *Mathematical Analysis*. At some point it is claimed that
$$
\int_0^1\left\lvert f(x + h,t) - f(x,t) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)\right\rvert\, \mathrm dt\leqq \int_0^1\sup_{0 < \theta < 1}{\left\lvert \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x + \theta h,t) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)\right\rvert}\, \mathrm dt
$$
for every $ x\in K $ and for every $ h $ such that $ f(x + h,t) $ is defined. I don’t get how to derive this inequality.

I know that
$$
\lvert f(x + h) - f(x)\rvert \leqq \lvert \mathrm df(-,t)(x)(h) \rvert + \lvert \sigma(h) \rvert
$$
for every $ t\in \left[0,1\right] $, where
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sigma(h)}{h} = 0\text{,}
$$
and
$$
\lvert \mathrm df(-,t)(x)(h) \rvert\leqq \lVert \mathrm df(-,t)(x) \rVert \lvert h\rvert
$$
where
$$
\lVert \mathrm df(-,t)(x) \rVert = \left\lvert \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t) \right\rvert\text{,}
$$
but I don’t know were to go from this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an application of the (univariate) mean value theorem to the function $x\mapsto f(x,t)$. For each $t$, $x$, $h$ the MVT asserts the existence of $\theta_{t,x,h}\in(0,1)$ such that
$$\frac{f(x+h, t) - f(x,t)}h=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x+\theta_{t,x,h} h, t).$$
It follows that
$$\begin{aligned}\left|\frac{f(x+h, t) - f(x,t)}h-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, t)\right|&=\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x+\theta_{t,x,h} h, t)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, t)\right|\\
&\le\sup_{0<\theta<1}\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x+\theta h, t)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, t)\right|.\end{aligned}$$
Now integrate over $t$ to get the result.

Answer (score 4):

There is some $h$ in the denominator missing:
$$\int_0^1\left | \frac{f(x+h,t)-f(x,t)}{h}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)\right |dt = \int_0^1 \left | \frac{1}{h}\int_0^1 \frac{d}{ds}(f(x+sh,t))ds-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)\right |dt \\ = \int_0^1\left |\int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x+sh,t)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)ds\right |dt \leq \int_0^1\int_0^1\sup_{0<\theta<1}\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x+\theta h,t)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)\right|dsdt \\ = \int_0^1\sup_{0<\theta<1}\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x+\theta h,t)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)\right|dt$$